# Error: Element must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I can't seem to grasp on what this online validator is telling me:

> cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'characterPower' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

(I get the the same error code for the 'weakness' element as well)

```
    <xs:element name="characterPower" type="xs:string">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="origin" type="originType" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="weakness">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="lethality" type="lethalType" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="originType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="alien" />
            <xs:enumeration value="radiation" />
            <xs:enumeration value="mutant" />
            <xs:enumeration value="skill" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="lethalType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="major" />
            <xs:enumeration value="minor" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

And this is the piece of the XML document that relates to it

```
        <characterPower origin="mutant">Weapon Expertise, Healing Factor, Master Martial Artist and Assassin</characterPower>
        <weakness lethality="minor">Poor Mental State</weakness>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow `characterPower` to both have an `origin` attribute *and* string content, extend `xs:string` via `xs:simpleContent` like this:

```
  <xs:element name="characterPower">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="origin" type="originType" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

You can do similarly for the `weakness` element.